# Get status of one specific line in git

Tags: git

I am actually working on a multilingual app and it's getting pretty boring to do the translation every now and then.

My language files are in simple Json format and I would love to know if there is any way to know if a specific line of a file has been changed for me to be able to create a script and re-translate what has been modified and translate what has been added.

Is there some command that would let me do something like

```
git status --line-Number 37
```

And get an output telling me if this line (Here, line 37) has in deed been moddified, added or anything else?

Thanks in advance and keep coding!

Comment: The `git status` command does not look at individual lines. You *can* use `git blame` for this, and blame knows to compare the working tree copy to the committed copy as well, but in general you might be better off using a smarter tool here. Json is specifically *not* ordered, so even if the file has apparently changed, it could be "the same" in terms of its json contents.

Comment: It sounds like you're ready to use a real translation automation tool. Something like [Mojito](https://www.mojito.global/).

Comment: Nice thank you!
I'll have a look at mojito! :)